# How can I switch tasks by keyboard search?

Tags: windows, desktop

For many years, I've used a series of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> commands to get the window that I want.

Now that I've gotten the zen of `iswitchb` in emacs — telling the name of what I want directly — I'd like to do the same for windows.

Is there a way to type, say, part of the title of a window and switch to it when a unique match is found?